# Using Google Analytics on a PHP redirect page

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a page that has a PHP header `Location` on it that sends the browser to a PDF file. How can I track visits to the `stakeholderreport` page or file downloads of the PDF?

Comment: The "duplicate" answer is heavily outdatet and consists of a single dead link. A proper answer these days would not need a link and describe file tracking via the Google measurement protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can't- once that header is sent the redirect begins. You either need to track the click on the page where the link to the PDF file is or you need to restructure your page with a delayed HTML `<meta>` redirect so that the Google Analytics script on the page has time to fire.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="seconds;URL=the-other-url">
```